# Is there a way to migrate the followers when you merge several proposals into another proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

I am thinking of doing a *CMS for all* proposal to cover:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22662/umbraco-cms
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15362/dotnetnuke
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18767/composite-c1
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2608/cms-development
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8740/silverstripe
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6810/kentico-cms
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers
- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers
  etc

I need to know if the stackoverflow crew would agree.
Will we be able to add tabs in the header for popular cms?
**Can you migrate the followers using an email process confirmation step?**
Merging the example questions at the same time should be possible too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think every follower should be migrated automatically.  Some will be disappointed and just go away.  But I think a simple "click here to support the new merged proposal" option would be a good idea, so that each of those followers first confirm that they'll give their support to the new site as well.

And, fwiw, I think you have a good idea to merge all those into one.

Comment: iv done it http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/62/ could you answer the second question? - btw i dunno what are the criteria to accept an answer on meta

Answer (score 2):

Typically what we are doing is

- closing as duplicate
- emailing the followers explaining what is going on, and urging them to follow the parent proposal

I think it'd be a bit much to force them to follow a new proposal; maybe they don't believe in the merge, etc.

Comment: The idea he suggested is having emails sent out to each follower of the other proposals that contained a link that would cause them to follow the merged proposal. It is basically what you are doing, but more automated.

Comment: @cha we don't *manually* email them... obviously. :P Yes, I open gmail, and I type in each user's address.. "Dear Joe Smith," I type, "Although you have been a dearly beloved member of our network for 34 days, and I've always enjoyed seeing you around these parts.."

Comment: I was talking Automated as in **10 people close to vote as merging** -> followers get email. As in, not initiated through moderators, but through the community. Whether or not that type of automation is good is a whole different question.

Comment: @cha oh yes, we have considered that -- merging is tricky though

Comment: Is merging finally available? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28483/cms-blog-engines

Comment: This seems to have stalled it's been a fair while since this was suggested. Maybe a blog post or some other communication would be useful to get peoples interest again now that there's been plenty of time for them to perhaps realise that individual CMS proposals aren't going to make it on their own, and that this would be a good compromise?