# Too many SE sites causes confusion

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange

- [More than 30 websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) have already been created through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).
- [More than 10 websites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) have already completed their beta stage and are waiting for launch.
- [More than 5 websites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) are in public beta stage.
- [More than 30 proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) are in commitment phase in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- [More than 500](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposals are listed in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Now it is really confusing to find a suitable site to ask a question.
As an example - I host a blog using [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/). Now I have a question about this hosting. I want to post it in a [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/). Where will I post? I have 2 options available now.

1. [WordPress answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
2. [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

**Are developers trying anything to solve this confusing matter?**

Comment: I see a sentence ending in a question mark, but I'm not quite sure what the question is. I mean, yes, they are, but what do you _really_ want to know?

Comment: @Popular Demand: I just trying to pay attention of the developers.

Comment: I must have mixed things up, so deleted the comments. Nothing to see, move along!

Comment: @Ivo, hm, suspicious... __I wonder what that comment could possibly be alluding to.__

Comment: I agree w/ OP, why so many sites?

Comment: I find it confusing. Take for example a question on SVN which is a server program (super user) used by programmers (stack overflow / server fault / programmers) also web developers. A generic question could fit in a number of sites.

Comment: @jon Because people have many questions to ask.

Comment: This is the same with SU and AU. A question about Ubuntu can belong on both. AFAIK this is intentional, to give more complicated and specialised questions the community they need.

Comment: @Wes: Ahm, no. IMHO, a generic question about the SVN functionality is best asked on SO or PR, while a question about certain frontends/applications are better asked at SU...I don't see how WM does fit into there...

Comment: @Bobby sorry I'm not familar with all the abbreviations. what's WM? It's my opinion that it confusing. Another example a question about apache pasting the httpd.conf asking why something doesn't work. Where does that belong? Again I think it may fit on three of the big three sites.

Comment: @Wes: WebMaster...at least I hope so, I was to lazy to check, though might be PW. Anyway, [that one would belong on ServerFault](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache), since it's a question about the server.

Comment: At some point, there may really be the need for a Q&A site for asking which Q&A site a specific question goes to. Seriously.

Comment: What we really need here is hierarchy.  Let's prefix every SE name with something like comp., rec., sci., soc., or something like that.  Sites that don't make it out of the commitment phase can go in .alt.

Comment: @Rejoice rejoice kbd is back: That would be Meta or the according Metas, there are quiet some `Does this question belong here` or `Where does this question belong` questions around.

Comment: @Bobby yeah, but the point will come at which people will be unsure *which* Meta to ask on!

Comment: @Rejoice rejoice kbd is back: If in doubt, it's this one, as long as there is no `meta.stackexchange` for all sites....what the...such a thing exists...

Comment: @Bobby meta.stackexchange is for SE1.0. For all SE2.0 needs, it is asked here.

Comment: @chanchal check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69876/is-there-a-way-to-migrate-the-followers-when-you-merge-several-proposals-into-ano

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible we've got too many Stack Exchange sites/categories?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133694/is-it-possible-weve-got-too-many-stack-exchange-sites-categories)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *How do I programmatically move the paddle in Pong while microwaving my startup's leased iPad connected via VPN to an Ubuntu client with horrible UI that is taking geotagged photos of brownian-motion-moving particles in O(n log² n) without harming my unicorn-branded Android-powered Rovio bicycle unit, which right now sits on  a shoddy shelf between bottles of homebrew?
>
>   The documentation is written in horrible English, the SOApi dependency is misbehaving and I can't blog my problem because russian hackers have pwned it.
>
>   PS: I dissed my GM yesterday by suggesting we play Monopoly instead. Could it be related?*

Here's what I'd do.

1. Tag your question.
2. Go on the site you'd like to ask on: how many tags would you have to create?

If the answer is two or more, you're probably on the wrong place.

Comment: Please tell me that's not a real quote.

Comment: @Wes Google is your friend :)

Comment: I thought we already established this question belonged on Home Improvement.

Comment: @Grace What question? Man, _this_ one is _totally_ different. It belongs to Tex, obviously.

Comment: Ooh, I see, you're right. I didn't notice that little change there. I almost directed you to the wrong site. What a mess up *that* would've been!

Comment: @Grace Luckily we can migrate from any site to any other site so that won't be a problem, we'll just have to pass through WebApps though.

Comment: This is the best question that has never been asked.