# Can we have a where to post FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is still annoying me. Referring to the same problem given here [Too many SE sites causes confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70771/too-many-se-sites-causes-confusion/)

1. Could we have an answer for all the
   "Main" SE sites what is and isn't
   acceptable.
2. Also useful would be example
   questions that may be deemed
   ambiguous where they belong along
   with an explanation of **Why?** they
   belong in a particular site.

   For example a generic question on SQL
   (From the tavern earlier), belongs on
   [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) where a question
   specific to a specific database 
   belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).
3. A list of things that aren't appropriate
   for each site would also be useful. 
   Discussion based post not appropriate
   etc.
4. If anyone is feeling up to it the reasons
   most closed questions get closed on each
   site. This helps everyone play nice.
5. I guess this would be a good place to ask
   where to ask any given question. Or it would
   be a good place to enquire if a question is in 
   a wrong place?

**Finally** I am hoping that the answers to this may make a useful FAQ entry all by themselves. If people want I'll try to edit the answers into the question if / when I get time though any help doing this would be appreciated. If there is anything useful I hope it gets built into the sites' FAQ's

Comment: Good idea... but I think this may be too broad to cover all in one spot, especially since the network is expanding. For a given question, the best process is probably to do a network-wide search at stackexchange.com, figure out which sites would be actively involved in the question, and then examine each FAQ individually to find where it fits. If it's close between 2-3, then asking a Meta question would be appropriate. Now, all that being said, expecting a layperson to go through such a process is wayyyy too much to ask...

Comment: Okay but I think we should give it some consideration as a community. Its important to have people posting in the right place. I'll try to make a start on this in the next few days- Hopefully. TBH I'm not a fan of all the splits.